# Access and Word 2010 merging one record depending on subform button clicked

Tags: ms-access, ms-word, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm working on a small program in which one letter in Word needs to be create when one button in a Access subform is clicked. 
The form represents one client and in the subform there are the list of commands done by this client. Next each command line (containing date and description), there is one button that trigger the maccro and create the letter. Until now, I succeed to create the word letter when one button is clicked but each command in the subform create a page in the word document.

Is it possible to keep only the command next to the button clicked and not all the command? 
I was looking for that kind of command :

```
"SELECT * FROM [Fusion]WHERE [id_client] = " & Forms!subform!id_client
```

but when I do it for the subform I have one error saying that the form doesn't exist...

Thanks for your help.

--**EDIT**--

Here is the code, the [Fusion] is my SQL request which get all the clients and the orders related to them.

```
Function Publipostage()

Dim mDoc As String
Dim strSQL As String
' Path of the letter
mDoc = "C:\...\LT000006.docx"
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Fusion]WHERE [id_client] = " & Forms!FormPatient!id_client

Dim oApp As New Word.Application
Dim oMainDoc As Word.Document
Dim sData As String

   oApp.Visible = True
      sData = "C:\...\Database1.accdb"

   Set oMainDoc = oApp.Documents.Open(mDoc)

      With oMainDoc.MailMerge
          .MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
          .OpenDataSource Name:=sData, SQLStatement:=strSQL
      End With

   With oMainDoc
       .MailMerge.Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
       .MailMerge.Execute
   End With

   oApp.Activate
   oApp.Documents.Parent.Visible = True
   oApp.Application.WindowState = 1
   oApp.ActiveWindow.WindowState = 1

Set oApp = Nothing
Set oMainDoc = Nothing

Exit Function

Err_Handle:
   Set oApp = Nothing
   Set oMainDoc = Nothing
      MsgBox "An error occurred..." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Err.Description
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your question is a bit unclear but if the button is on the subform you can use

`Me.id_client`

if it is on the main form try

`Forms("MAIN FORM NAME").Controls("SUB FORM NAME").Form.Controls("id_client")`

**Edit**

Or `Me.Parent.Controls("id_client")`

When referencing a subform you must reference the parent form first.

If you only want to print 1 command from the list then it seems your SQL needs to change to reference that command. i.e.

`"SELECT * FROM [Fusion] WHERE [id_command] = " & Me.id_command`

This is just an example as I am unaware of your table structure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the button is on the subform and the subform has the form :  

    `Date1     NameCommand1     [ButtonToCreateLetter]  <br/>   
     Date2     NameCommand2     [ButtonToCreateLetter]  <br/> 
    ...`   

I want that after pushing one button the information of the form and the information of the line of the button's subform are taking into the Word letter.

Tell me if it's still unclear.
I will try your solution.

Comment: You stated you have code that works just not exactly what you are aiming for if you could provide that it might be a good start. Seems like it might be easiest to write the query and use a recordset but I am still unsure as to what is going on. If you could provide additional information or additional code that is working I am sure I can help

Comment: I will edit my question with the code and one picture it will be easier

Comment: just seems you need to write a bit more SQL i.e. `"SELECT * FROM [Fusion] WHERE [id_client] = " & Forms!FormPatient!id_client & " AND order_id = " & Me.order_id` or whatever your unique identifier is for an order.

Comment: That's my problem because unlike the field "id_client", I don't know the name I should put for the order since in Access when I create my form I create only one field with one name and the program creates the list than I don't know how to specify the line I want...

Comment: So there is no key for the current record in the subform? I know you only create one form I am assuming this a continuous form which will populate with each sub record. These are actually individual forms each with there own data so that is not a problem you just need to find out what unique key you can use even if it is something like Date And CommandName. Access does not change them to Date1 and Date2 it would just be Date for each Form.

Comment: Great!! it works. Just put the name of the unique key of the subform does the trick.

Thank you very much for your help :)