# I need to create a button to do mail merge from Access subform to Word

Tags: vba, ms-access, mailmerge

I created a client database. In the database, each of the clients are grouped by a unique company ID. The user can search all the clients in the company by entering a company ID in the following cell on the main form.

```
([Forms]![frmNavigationForm]![Text78])
```

Right now I want to do mail merge from the subform to word after by clicking a button on the main form.

I got some ideas from the following link: [Access and Word 2010 merging one record depending on subform button clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20424161/access-and-word-2010-merging-one-record-depending-on-subform-button-clicked)

Issue:
When I try to run the code, it shows run time error "4198": Command Failed.

When I run debug the this command was highlighted

```
.OpenDataSource Name:=sData, SQLStatement:=strSQL
```

Can someone tell me how to fix the error?

```
Private Sub Command203_Click()

Dim mDoc As String
Dim strSQL As String

mDoc = "C:\~~~\800052 ENG w Macro titus.docx"
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM![frmNavigationForm]![frmKYCGenerator] WHERE [RS ID]=" & [Forms]![frmNavigationForm]![Text78]

Dim oApp As New Word.Application
Dim oMainDoc As Word.Document
Dim sData As String

   oApp.Visible = True
      Data = "C:\~~~\Database - Users - PR.accdb"

   Set oMainDoc = oApp.Documents.Open(mDoc)

      With oMainDoc.MailMerge
      .MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
      .OpenDataSource Name:=sData, SQLStatement:=strSQL
      End With

   With oMainDoc
       .MailMerge.Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
       .MailMerge.Execute
   End With

   oApp.Activate
   oApp.Documents.Parent.Visible = True
   oApp.Application.WindowState = 1
   oApp.ActiveWindow.WindowState = 1

Set oApp = Nothing
Set oMainDoc = Nothing

Exit Sub

Err_Handle:
   Set oApp = Nothing
   Set oMainDoc = Nothing
      MsgBox "An error occurred..." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: You should add an `Option Explicit` to top of your code. Makes it easier to find hard-to-spot typos like sData/Data

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the name of your datasource is empty. I think that:

```
Data = "C:\~~~\Database - Users - PR.accdb"
```

should be:

```
sData = "C:\~~~\Database - Users - PR.accdb"
```

Comment: good catch. I already fix it, so I don't think that is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `Option Explicit` to top of your module code.

That would find the issue identified by @peter and any other undeclared or typo error variables

It also looks like you merged a couple names together in your SQL
I assume you know what you're doing in your SQL statement - either you forgot the table name - or you're actually using the query/table defined by `[frmNavigationForm]![frmKYCGenerator]`

Because you don't mention any table name I'll assume the latter. In that case...

**Change this**

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM![frmNavigationForm]![frmKYCGenerator] WHERE [RS ID]=" & [Forms]![frmNavigationForm]![Text78]
```

**To this**

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & [Forms]![frmNavigationForm]![frmKYCGenerator] & "] WHERE [RS ID]=" & [Forms]![frmNavigationForm]![Text78]
```

Comment: Thank you for the help and correcting me. [frmNavigationForm] is the main form and [frmKYCGenerator] is the subform. So I changed the Statement to the following instead.
 
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Form]![frmNavigationForm] WHERE [RS ID] = " & [Forms]![frmNavigationForm]![Text78]

But now the database is telling me "odbc Microsoft access driver login failed" and could not find the following file.

    "C:\~~~\Database - Users - PR.mdb"

Do you know why it doesn't recognize the currect file format (.accdb)?

Comment: Change your code above to show what we're actually dealing with now. And for your own debugging purposes you should be use `Debug.Print` or `Msgbox` to show yourself what's being passed to `.OpenDataSource`

Comment: What is the name of the Access table you're trying to get data from? You can't run a SQL query on a Form Name.